# How to create a private domain name?

Tags: windows, dns, subdomain, domain-name, easyphp

In order to debug some functionality of a website project I would like to know if it's possible on my local host to access my `http://127.0.0.1/projectName/test1/public` folder with a custom domain name and create other subdomain?

I'm working with easyPHP on Windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOSTS File: In Notepad (as Administrator) open the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

To make foo.bar.com resolve to 127.0.0.1 simply add the line

```
127.0.0.1       foo.bar.com
```

You can add as many as you like.